# OGL ES 2.0 Orthogonal Matrix result position unexpected

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm having some trouble figuring out, why my triangle is not rendered at the expected position.

I want to draw this triangle:

```
private float vVertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                              1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                              1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
```

First I create a Projection Matrix as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617467/glortho-opengl-es-2-0-variant-how-fix-blank-screen)

```
float aspect_ratio = 800.0f/480.0f; 
ortho_matrix(-aspect_ratio, aspect_ratio, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, PROJECTION_MATRIX);
```

Then I create a View Matrix and multiply those two:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(VIEW_MATRIX, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);    
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, PROJECTION_MATRIX, 0, VIEW_MATRIX, 0);
```

Now I send the mvpMatrix to my Shader,

```
String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 vPosition; \n" +
                      "uniform mat4 orthoMatrix;" +
                      "void main()\n" +
                      "{\n" +
                      "    gl_Position = vPosition * orthoMatrix;" +
                      "}";
```

where the vertices are translated using this matrix.
However, this is not the result I was expecting.

The following image is the result of the above code:
[image: Wrong Triangle Position]

I expected the triangle to have its origin in 0, 0, 0 - so in the center of the screen like this:
[image: Expected Triangle Position]

From the above code, can anyone tell me what I did wrong, or what I did miss?

*edit*
Ok, it seems the koordinates are somehow mirrored...
so it looks like this

```
1 ----+---- -1
```

When I inverse the aspect_ratio parameters in the ortho_matrix call it looks right. But why is this nessecary?

Comment: Are you sure your aspect ratio is right? It should actually be `480.0f/800.0f` ;) Unless you're using it landscape.

Comment: I think I'm right, the device is rotated 90° to the left
Also I called 
    setRequestedOrientation(0);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );

Where I think it sets the orientation to landscape!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the vertex shader multiplication backwards.

It should be :

`gl_Position = orthoMatrix * vPosition;`

Comment: When I change it that way, i don't see anything on screen, so there must be something different wrong.

Comment: Are you transposing the matrix when you upload it? Can you post the uniform upload code? @Zerd1984

Comment: `mMVMatrixUniformLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(m_Shader.getProgramId(), "orthoMatrix");

GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixUniformLocation, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);`

Comment: Interesting, when I use 
`Matrix.frustumM(PROJECTION_MATRIX, 0, -aspect_ratio, aspect_ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);`
instead of the ortho_matrix function I now get the same result as when I was calculating the gl_Position in the opposite way..

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then. I'm quite sure it should be `ortho * vPosition`, and you'll also notice that that's the way they are multiplying it in the other question you cited. Is that a custom function `ortho_matrix`? Is there a reason you don't use the API function `Matrix.orthoM`? @Zerd1984

Comment: I didn't know of this function ;) Thx, thats easier... But actually the same result ;)
I edited my question. It seems the x axis is mirrored, do you have a wild guess why that happens? I think that might be the whole problem

Comment: You're probably 'looking at' the triangle from the wrong side. Try putting the lookAt eye on the +z axis (-z is pointing into the screen). @Zerd1984